# fuzz testing for message filters?

Tags: ros, message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Message filter](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/lunar-devel/utilities/message_filters) is one of the important components in ROS, which monitors data from different sources and do the synchronization via registered callback functions, is there any exiting fuzz testing tools or thoughts for this component?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286622/fuzz-testing-for-message-filters?/) by [cathyshen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33203/cathyshen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on 2018-04-09**:
I am currently working on something which enables one to do ROS node level fuzzy testing. However it is too early for making it public right now. Stay tuned on discourse.ros.org for threads in the "project" category ;-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are unit tests for this library, but I doubt that any of them are fuzz tests: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/lunar-devel/utilities/message_filters/test

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cathyshen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33203/cathyshen/) on 2018-03-27**:
Yeah, they are not fuzz actually.